# protractor - How to retrieve value for 'ng-disabled' using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to protractor and want to get the value returned by 'ng-disabled' so that I can use this value further manipulation. When I try to get the value with getAttribute() it does not return any value.

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-disabled="campaign.reportStatus"]')).getAttribute('value').then(function (result) {
console.log('result is' +result);
});
```

Please provide me the solution for this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What value are you trying to get? Please post your html code and any more details that you want to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use `getAttribute('disabled')` to get disabled status.

```
element(by.css('button')).getAttribute('disabled')).then(function (result) {
console.log('result is' +result);
});
```